# SQL Server : stored procedure takes too much time on client machine

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 for a web application in Visual Studio 2015.

We have test instance for our application on AWS. We have SQL Server also residing on same AWS instance.

With this stored procedure takes less than a minute to execute.

Our customer also has Windows Server with SQL Server 2008 R2 and application residing on the same server.

But the same stored procedure takes too much time to execute on customer's server - around 10 minutes or maybe even more.

What could be the reason? What settings or conditions or properties for SQL Server or application or Windows Server can we check to reduce time taken to execute that stored procedure?

How to find out the reason taking too much time to execute the stored procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: run the execution plan..

Answer (score 1):

Below is an approach you could follow..

1.Try updating statistics on all tables involved in the stored proc

2.if updating stats doesn't help,you could check the execution plan ,you could compare execution plan you are getting on two machines and try to see differences.Execution plan is dependant on hardware as well..so try to see if two machines are configured correctly

3.You could also check if there are any locking,blockings observed,since each machine may have different workload